# DE0 Nano LEDs consecutively on and off

Tags: vhdl, fpga, quartus

Please understand my very low skill-set on the code. I am trying to learn to be better.

Using DE0 Nano board, I am trying to write VHDL to simulate all available LEDs on the board (8 of them)

I labeled them LED0 ~ LED7. Using 50 MHZ and 1/2 s counter, I wanted to operate individual LEDs in order.

For example, if these individual bits represents on and off of the LEDs.
1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0 -> 0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0 -> 0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0 and so on. At the end, counter would reset back to 0 to repeat the sequence again.

Please view my code below with these questions/issues.

1) I get one 1/2 s pause after 8th LED. Why? How do I fix this?

2) Even if i put the variable counter as 8, it repeats as 16 thus I had to implement the reset of the counter to 0. (marked as question 2 in the code)

3) Is there any better way to write these codes? It is completely messy. Could you give tips on any other function or method I can use to shorten this codes?

Please let me know if any questions!

THANKS A LOT FOR THE HELP.

```
entity ledtest is
port(
    clk_50mhz : in std_logic ;
    reset_btn : in std_logic;
    green_led : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
);
end entity;


architecture behave of ledtest is

signal clk_1hz : std_logic ;
signal scaler : integer range 0 to 25000000 ;
signal counter : integer range 0 to 8;
signal LED  : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

begin

clk_1hz_process : process( clk_50mhz , reset_btn )
begin
    if (reset_btn = '0') then 
        clk_1hz <= '0';
        scaler <= 0;
        counter <= 0;
    elsif(rising_edge(clk_50mhz)) then 
        if (scaler < 25000000) then 
            scaler <= scaler + 1 ;
            clk_1hz <= '0';
        else
            scaler <= 0;
            clk_1hz <= '1';
            counter <= counter + 1;
            if (counter >= 8) then  --------question 2
                counter <= 0;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process clk_1hz_process;

blinking_process : process (clk_1hz,reset_btn)
begin
    if (reset_btn = '0') then 
        LED(0) <= '0';

    elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) AND counter = 1 then
        LED(0) <= not LED(0) ;
        LED(7) <=  '0' ; 
    elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) AND counter = 2 then
        LED(1) <= not LED(1) ;
        LED(0) <= not LED(0) ;
    elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) AND counter = 3 then
        LED(2) <= not LED(2) ;
        LED(1) <= not LED(1) ;
    elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) AND counter = 4 then
        LED(3) <= not LED(3) ;
        LED(2) <= not LED(2) ;
    elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) AND counter = 5 then
        LED(4) <= not LED(4) ;
        LED(3) <= not LED(3) ;
    elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) AND counter = 6 then
        LED(5) <= not LED(5) ;
        LED(4) <= not LED(4) ;
    elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) AND counter = 7 then
        LED(6) <= not LED(6) ;
        LED(5) <= not LED(5) ;
    elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) AND counter = 8 then
        LED(7) <= not LED(7) ;
        LED(6) <= not LED(6) ;
    end if;

end process blinking_process;

green_led(0) <= LED(0);
green_led(1) <= LED(1);
green_led(2) <= LED(2);
green_led(3) <= LED(3);
green_led(4) <= LED(4);
green_led(5) <= LED(5);
green_led(6) <= LED(6);
green_led(7) <= LED(7);
end behave;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your readers squint real hard they can treat the original post as one question and two issues. (A questions is singular.)

> Please view my code below with these questions/issues.
>
> 1) I get one 1/2 s pause after 8th LED. Why? How do I fix this?

There are 9 counter values  (0 to 8) and only 8 LEDs (7 downto 0). No assignments occur in the half second between assigning counter to 0 and incrementing by 1 again.

> 2) Even if i put the variable counter as 8, it repeats as 16 thus I had to implement the reset of the counter to 0. (marked as question 2 in the code)

This issue is tied in with 1). The requirement for evaluating counter greater than or equal to 8 is caused by assigning counter to 8, again there are 9 values and  only 8 LEDs. Note that's a synchronous load to 0 and not an asynchronous reset.

> 3) Is there any better way to write these codes? It is completely messy. Could you give tips on any other function or method I can use to shorten this codes?

Because you're attempting to go directly to FPGA instead of simulating the focus on tips should relate to the question 1) and how to fix it. There are also some synthesis issues, here gating clocks by adding enables to the conditions in if statement `elsif` alternatives. There's also the issue of design specification complexity and the amount of debugging effort associated with the number of lines of code.

First there are flip flops for all LED elements as well a counter. We can reduce the number of flip flops to one for each LED element by using a ring counter (not to be confused with a Johnson counter).

Assignments to `green_led` (the std_logic_vector) can be from LED (the std_logic_vector) instead of element by element. There's a one to one correspondence between element indices on both side of the assignment(s).

Also to allow simulation you could virtualize the time interval of a half second loaded into `scalar`.  This has the effect of having fewer clocks represent a half second. The idea is simulation doesn't have to take the 10+ seconds of 100 million clock transitions per second (rising and falling edges).

Throw all these together and the code is changed to look like:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ledtest is
    generic (half_second:   integer := 24999999); -- zero identity
    -- the generic allows fewer clocks per second for simulation
    port (
        clk_50mhz:  in std_logic;
        reset_btn:  in std_logic;
        green_led:  out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture behave of ledtest is
    signal clk_1hz:  std_logic;
    signal scaler:      integer range 0 to half_second;
    -- signal counter:  integer range 0 to 8;               -- DELETED
    signal ring_counter:    std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);  -- ADDED
    signal LED:             std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    signal LED0I:           std_logic;                      -- ADDED

begin
    LED0I <= '1' when LED = "00000000" else 
             '0';

clk_1hz_process:  
    process (clk_50mhz, reset_btn)
    begin
        if reset_btn = '0' then 
            clk_1hz <= '0';
            scaler <= 0;
            -- counter <= 0;
        elsif rising_edge(clk_50mhz) then 
            if scaler /= half_second then 
                scaler <= scaler + 1;
                clk_1hz <= '0';
            else
                scaler <= 0;
                clk_1hz <= '1';
                -- counter <= counter + 1;
                -- if counter >= 8 then  --------question 2
                --     counter <= 0;
                -- end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process clk_1hz_process;

blinking_process:  
    process (clk_1hz, reset_btn)
    begin
        if reset_btn = '0' then

            LED <= (others => '0');
            -- LED(0) <= '0';
        elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) then
            LED <= LED(6 downto 0) & (LED(7) or LED0I);
            -- ring counter with a roulette ball lauch after reset

        -- elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) AND counter = 1 then
        --     LED(0) <= not LED(0);
        --     LED(7) <=  '0';
        -- elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) AND counter = 2 then
        --     LED(1) <= not LED(1);
        --     LED(0) <= not LED(0);
        -- elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) AND counter = 3 then
        --     LED(2) <= not LED(2);
        --     LED(1) <= not LED(1);
        -- elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) AND counter = 4 then
        --     LED(3) <= not LED(3);
        --     LED(2) <= not LED(2);
        -- elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) AND counter = 5 then
        --     LED(4) <= not LED(4);
        --     LED(3) <= not LED(3);
        -- elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) AND counter = 6 then
        --     LED(5) <= not LED(5);
        --     LED(4) <= not LED(4);
        -- elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) AND counter = 7 then
        --     LED(6) <= not LED(6);
        --     LED(5) <= not LED(5);
        -- elsif rising_edge(clk_1hz) AND counter = 8 then
        --     LED(7) <= not LED(7);
        --     LED(6) <= not LED(6);
        end if;

    end process blinking_process;
    green_led <= led;
    -- green_led(0) <= LED(0);
    -- green_led(1) <= LED(1);
    -- green_led(2) <= LED(2);
    -- green_led(3) <= LED(3);
    -- green_led(4) <= LED(4);
    -- green_led(5) <= LED(5);
    -- green_led(6) <= LED(6);
    -- green_led(7) <= LED(7);
end architecture behave;
```

(Also note the default generic value scalar is reset and loaded to has been decremented to include the unity 0 in the 250,000,000 clocks be half second. The equality test for `half_second` is simpler than using magnitude comparison.)

Using a ring counter reduces complexity and side steps the issue of a counter range of 9.

The ring counter has a flourish added, the reset value is all '0's which are detected by signal `LED0I` which is used to start the ring counter after reset. It prevents all the LEDs from being lit during reset.

You can use a testbench with the number of clocks comprising a half second to a much smaller number allowing fast simulation with small waveform dump files:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ledtest_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of ledtest_tb is
    signal clk:         std_logic := '0';
    signal reset_btn:   std_logic := '1';
    signal green_led:   std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
begin
    DUT:
    entity work.ledtest
        generic map (half_second => 7)
        port map (
            clk_50mhz => clk,
            reset_btn => reset_btn,
            green_led => green_led
        );
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 0.5 sec / 7;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 19 sec then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 0.5 sec;
        reset_btn <= '0';
        wait for 0.5 sec;
        reset_btn <= '1';
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

And that gives:

[image: ledtest_tb.jpg]

You could eliminate the generic map in the testbench instantiation of ledtest to demonstrate the difference in simulation time and dump file size inherent with simulating every clock transition with a 50 MHz clock. The idea here is it's easier to troubleshoot a simulation than it is to guess from what you can see (here the LEDs). Because the code description was simplified there was debugging required using the original code as a starting point. It did rely on a knowledge of digital electronics and VHDL.

The simulation was done with ghdl and gtkwave.

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you so much for the detailed information. I was trying to write the led_tb file to simulate the clock... this is perfect, and also thanks for the ghdl / gtkwave information! I will try this as soon as I get home! Thank you again!